# Nice Git architecture for server / client?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, github, symlink

I'm about to start a pretty huge project.

This project is a website.

- The backend will be made with Node
- The frontend will be made mostly with Angular

Backend is going to be an API (which is cool with Angular) but also (later) for an Android app.

Frontend is going to be a fork of this repo : https://github.com/maxime1992/webTemplate and I want to be able to pull from upstream to keep the fork up to date.

I am wondering. How should I manage it?

1. Should I create only one repo, containing back and frontend with Git submodule or subtree.
2. Should I create two separated repos, one for the frontend, one for the backend and then use symlink to have them together? But if someone wants to run it on Windows ... Too bad.

I want this project to be open source on GitHub so I would like to have something clear and easy for everyone :)

Tell me how you would do it, what's good, what's wrong ... I'm really curious!

Comment: Git isn't really suited for more than 1 project per repository. I'd probably use npm or something in one project to fetch the other as a dependency, or even set up a 3rd repo depending on the front- and back- end repo's.

Comment: Say more about how symlinking comes into play here? If the backend is truly a stand alone API, which seems like a good plan by the way, you should be free to keep it in its own repo and deploy it however you like. The only point of contact for your front end would be the formatted calls. What needs to be symlinked to what here?

Comment: @lostphilosopher you're right, i thought it would be nice to avoid creating a second server, just to serve static files. But it seems kinda logic now !

Comment: @Kenney how could i do that ? I'm interested in npm but i don't understand why an api or an interface should become a npm module ?

Comment: If you're using Node you'll probably want to use npm for dependency management. Git submodules are horrible, don't use them.
Typically, you'd want an interface to be a separate project, used by both server and client, specifying the contract in a stable way. The 3rd project i mentioned would be a 'packaging' project, combining the server and client projects. But, having a separate, stable interface project, used by both server and client to define their 'contract' is not a bad idea.

Comment: I agree with Kenney but not because submodules are horrible (they have their uses) rather because you should do what your language community does - make it npm compatible if your'e using js (not necessarily just node), make it go-getable if you're using go, make it cpan compatible if using Perl etc.. If you expect people to use your code, don't surprise them with non-standard packaging

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comments, Git submodules (or Git subtrees) are not the right solution for this. Use a dependency management tool for this, which will work cross-platform (Linux, Mac, Windows), and is the standard way of doing this.

Separating your backend and frontend into separate projects is a good idea, as it will allow you to manage projects independently and add functionality or additional client applications later without bloating your application.

Since you're already using Angular for the frontend, I suggest you take a look at [Bower](https://bower.io), which is the de-facto standard dependency management tool for frontend projects. It allows you to define a `bower.json` file to define your dependencies, e.g. Angular and other frontend libraries, allowing you to assemble your frontend project without having to download and store libraries manually.

In your backend project, you would then also add a `bower.json` file which declares your frontend project as a *dependency* by pointing to its Git location and branch. Bower will then take care of downloading your frontend project and adding it into your backend project.

Check out some of the popular Bower tutorials for more info on this...

You can use `bower link` to automatically create symlinks between your projects - this will work across operating systems as well.

Some other tools that you might want to check out:

- [Yeoman](https://yeoman.io) for scaffolding a base project. There are some nice generators for scaffolding Angular projects, including things like LESS/SASS and Bootstrap (https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)
- [Wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) for automatically wiring your Bower dependencies into your `index.html` file.

Getting your initial project setup right will be important. You can start small and grow things to a more advanced configuration later.