# We have front-end project and backend project in each a Git repo and share some functions/classes, how?

Tags: git

What is the proven best way to share elements between 2 Git repos?

Say, I have an AngularJS frontend project written with JavaScript. Now we have a backend written in Node.js. This can, of course be any language and any other use case. Say a spring Java project. And another similar spring Java project. Both share a utility library that you have written. Where to put it and easily share it? Some utility functions are just used in both projects.

In SVN this was super easy. You create on big repo. You want project `a`? well you just checkout that folder plus say project/folder `global`. Feel free starting to code.

Now what about Git? Did we make a step back there?

[I read about submodules and sub trees, and they look complex. They seem to lead to a lot of trouble.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Submodules#Issues-with-Submodules) Especially when you are not used to this.

[next reference for trouble](https://codingkilledthecat.WordPress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/)

I am sure this problem has been solved thousand of times. I just wonder how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way of separating these is like the following:

- Move all of the shared classes (or code) into a third project. Create a Git repo for it.
- Develop this shared project independently of the others, tag it when ready, create a release, etc.
- Use a dependency management tool to include the shared library in the two other projects.

Dependency management tools that are good fits for this:

- Maven for Java projects/libraries (`pom.xml`)
- npm for Node.js projects/libraries (`package.json`)
- Bower for frontend JS projects/libraries (`bower.json`)

Try to stay clear of Git submodules, they are complex and will be cumbersome to manage. Use one of the above dependency management tools, use your shared code just like you would use any other third-party library (Spring, Angular, Express, ...)

If you want to link your development projects together locally so you can work on the shared code without having to commit/release/update the library for the changes to appear, you can make use of the `link` feature in both Bower and npm. See the following questions for detailed answers about these:

- `bower link`: [Nice Git architecture for server / client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706354/nice-git-architecture-for-server-client/31717007#31717007)
- `npm link`: [How can I commit changes that I've made in node_modules back to git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722344/how-can-i-commit-changes-that-ive-made-in-node-modules-back-to-git/31723505#31723505)

Comment: ok say I am writing a lot of new code. I write this for project `A` that is written in agnular, that uses say utilities `B`. Now I import the code using bower. I add changes to the code of `B` in my dependencies. I have to manually copy them back to the repo of `B` and commit them there. Right? This is the new way to program? Way to code in 2015?

Comment: You can use `bower link` to achieve exactly what you're looking for. It's made for this purpose (linking projects locally during development). No need to copy things back and forth. Check out my more detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706354/nice-git-architecture-for-server-client/31717007#31717007

Comment: BTW: No need for the sarcasm, just trying to help... :-)

Comment: hehe sorry, I was just disappointed with submodules and subtrees so much. Didnt mean to unload it onto you. Is there something for npm as well?

Comment: Don't worry - I can understand the frustration.

Comment: npm has an identical feature: `npm link`. See here for a more detailed answer/example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722344/how-can-i-commit-changes-that-ive-made-in-node-modules-back-to-git/31723505#31723505

Comment: add the thing about the link to the answer. It is new to me and was to the team leader as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the following useful guidelines during naming `git` Repositories

- Use `lowercase`, `kebab-case` for repository names
- Repository name should consist of three parts: `<project>-<platform>-<module>`, the `<module>` part is optional and the `<platform>` part is one of these: *android*, *ios*, *backend*, *frontend*, *rn*, *unity* - Repository name should consist of three parts: `<project>-<platform>-<module>`, the `<module>` part is optional and the `<platform>` part is one of these: *android*, *ios*, *backend*, *frontend*, *rn*, *unity*
- Examples of repository names: `surge-android`, `surge-ios`, `surge-backend-api`, `surge-frontend-admin`, `surge-rn`   - Examples of repository names: `surge-android`, `surge-ios`, `surge-backend-api`, `surge-frontend-admin`, `surge-rn`
- If project name consists of multiple words, use dashes as a separator, e.g. `rich-uncles-frontend`    - If project name consists of multiple words, use dashes as a separator, e.g. `rich-uncles-frontend`
- If project has multiple versions, use *v1*, *v2* suffixes, e.g. `futupilot-backend-api-v1`, `futupilot-backend-api-v2`    - If project has multiple versions, use *v1*, *v2* suffixes, e.g. `futupilot-backend-api-v1`, `futupilot-backend-api-v2`
- If API, web or RN are mixed in a single repository, use `js-monorepo` as a platform identifier, e.g. `ordr-js-monorepo`   - If API, web or RN are mixed in a single repository, use `js-monorepo` as a platform identifier, e.g. `ordr-js-monorepo`
- The same rules above apply to public repositories - The same rules above apply to public repositories
- Each project must have proper *.gitignore*, ignoring temporary files and binaries - Each project must have proper *.gitignore*, ignoring temporary files and binaries
- Each project must have a *README.md* file with instructions and other important notes about how to build it and run it    - Each project must have a *README.md* file with instructions and other important notes about how to build it and run it

Reference
https://github.com/strvcom/strv-guidelines/blob/master/git.md

Answer (score 0):

you can use Maven for this purpose, i have applied same logic in my application. as illustrated below.

```
com.org.abc (maven - group - id)
com.abc.util (common-util -- maven - artifact-id)
```

my util project is sub project of com.org.abc.

now let us assume, i need to use util project for another project.

```
com.org.xyz
```

now all you have to do is, you have to add dependency com.abc.util jar in your com.org.xyz pom.xml file.

Maven is project management tool, for this purpose.refer this tutorial

[maven tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/)